# How can I obtain the first 2 decimal places of a number without considering the weight of successive decimal places in Java?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

In Java I have a **Number** object that can have decimal digits.

For instance it could be something like: **123.456789**

Where **123** is the integer part of my number and **456789** is the decimal part.

Ok. How can I obtain the same number with only the first 2 decimal places without considering the weight of successive decimal places.

For example if I want the number with only the first 2 decimal places I want obtain **123.45** and not **123.46** (aproximated because the following decimal place is >5).

I also need that if I have an integer number as **3** I want obtain it with its 2 first decimal places, that is **3.00**

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try setScale method like below

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("123.456789");
BigDecimal bg2 = value.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println(bg2);

Output:
123.45

For input as 3, output is 3.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
decimalFormat.format(123.456789);
```

output : 123.45

For input as 3, output is 3